# Using SharedPreferences to store data for use by Broadcast Receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, flags

I'm writing some code that turns airplane mode on or off (depending on user choice) when the screen turns on. I've kept flags for the user's choice (0 for off and 1 for on). For some reason though, no matter what the user picks, the value for the choice (airplanei) is always 1 in the activity. I'm sure the error is somewhere in the code I've posted; incorrect use of SharedPreferences most likely.

Code for Activity:-

```
protected void airplane(int i) {
    // Store flag in SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences flags = this.getSharedPreferences("toggleflags",
                    MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = flags.edit();
    if (i == 0)
        editor.putInt("airplanei", 0);
    else if (i == 1)
        flags.edit().putInt("airplanei", 1);
    else if (i == -1)
        flags.edit().putInt("airplanei", -1);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Code in Broadcast Reciever: -

```
public class Screen_On extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences flag = context.getSharedPreferences("toggleflags", 0);
    int i = flag.getInt("airplanei", 1);
    if (i == 0) {
            //Code to turn airplane mode off
    } else if (i == 1) {
            //Code to turn airplane mode on
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Matt already said you actually create two new instances of `Editor` but commit only first:

```
flags.edit().putInt("airplanei", 1); // New editor here
...
flags.edit().putInt("airplanei", -1);
...
editor.commit(); // Commit first editor instance
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe I made such a silly mistake. Picked this answer since it was more thorough but thanks to Matt for his answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

When (i == 0) you use editor.putInt() and for (i == 1) and (i == -1) you use flags.edit().

I believe you should use editor.putInt() for them all.